# Microsoft Dynamics CRM API

Tags: c#, rest, soap, dynamics-crm

I've been tasked to create an API where a web page (developed externally) should be able to communicate with a CRM system. I've looked into the CRM SDK and created a couple of C# classes that perform some basic operations to get a feeling of it, but my main issue now is what should I give the web page's developer so that he can use what I have. Does it have to be a REST/SOAP API hosted on the domain of the CRM so that the web page can send queries or can I create a DLL from the c# project and give that to the web page's developer?

In fact, how would it work out if it's a REST API if CRM is hosted by Dynamics/Microsoft?

Comment: Why can't this developer use the CRM API directly?

Comment: Hi Jason, are you referring to the REST API(just found that CRM 2016 has one) or the one I used in c#? Anyhow I think the excuse was that he wasn't familiar so I they wanted me to develop the methods and then he could just pass the parameters to it (such as add new person/ update attribute etc)

Comment: So you are just creating a wrapper? That being the case, how is the developer going to be interfacing with it? If through a browser then some type of REST based may be better or if through a WinApp of some kind then a WCF WebService. Really it depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to create a wrapper around the Dynamics CRM Api to support development of an application that interfaces with Dynamics CRM. There are two ways to do this:

1. Create a hosted web service.
2. Generate a DLL with public methods.

If you are okay with the developer-user having to configure a connection string for Dynamics CRM and the application is being developed in a .NET language and the CRM server is addressable from the location where the application runs than # 2, generate a DLL with public methods, is the easier answer.

If any of those are not true you are likely to find that # 1, a hosted web service, is a better fit.

Comment: Hi Nicknow, Thank you for your reply. Are you aware of how does it work with custom entities? There is a tool that generates early-bounds when using the application API, is that the case with the WEB API too?